# Removing no data in raster (DEM) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, dem, srtm

I'm trying to work with this DEM in ArcMap, which is TANDEM. But, I have areas where the altitude is not normal, since it tends to shoot (which are the areas that look like clouds).

How can I fix the dem so that the dimensions come out between 100 to 120m or is there a way to fix or correct the DEM?

[image]

Comment: You should add the software you use to the body of the  text as well as to the title - and add a tag for it as well

Answer (score -2):

I'm still not quite sure what you want to do with the raster. (If you could attach a histogram of the data distribution, it might explain your needs more clearly).

From the screenshot, I see that the DEM values are between -432509 and 219546. I assume you only want to keep values between 100 and 120.

For this task, a raster calculator would be appropriate. (For more information: [ArcGIS Help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm))

```
Con("streams">120 | "streams"<100, -9999, "streams")
```

This means that for values less than 100 or greater than 120, make it -9999 and leave the other values as they are.

Also, if you noticed that I am using a joint judgment condition with an adjustment for the value of the condition being true. Then perhaps you will find that you can do more with this approach.

For example, if you think there are some excessively high outliers, perhaps you can make a filter by a condition of >1000 and bring those outliers back to their proper level.

Finally, I suggest that you try again to read the data description documentation before doing the above steps. Perhaps the publisher of the data has intentionally left some outliers and there are a code-meaning cross-reference for these outliers in data document.

I hope this answer helps, and I wish you all the best with your project!

Comment: You need to change the "streams" in the expression to the name of your raster.

Comment: What is -9999 doing  here?

Comment: Perhaps change it to Con(R<120,R)×Con(R>100,1). BTW comma here is decimal separator, not everybody follows US rules:( In any case no solution for gaps that will appear.

Comment: `-9999` represents the `nodata` place. It can be easily selected and identified in later procsses.

Comment: I need to perform statistical calculations from a mask extracted from the dem (since I need only one section), but for this I need to fix the tandem, since the values are very high. And as my teacher explains to me I need to remove the error areas and apply mask, but I really don't know how to fix the errors.

Comment: You must first identify the reason for the appearance of the error area. This determines whether you should discard or fix these areas. In general, there are usually predefined error codes (in this case, the value of the error area is usually uniform). You need to check the dataset documentation to confirm whether the error value meets the predefined error code or not. (1/2)

Comment: If it is not an error code, then generally you will consult other sources of elevation data, map data, etc. to confirm the true condition of these areas. Are these areas are peaks (in this case, it is usually acceptable to use the highest values of the around areas), or the variance of the elevation is relatively large (in this case, it is more appropriate to do overlay analysis with other elevation datasets or just use an elevation raster map without error areas). (2/2)